# $location.path('mypath') is not working even when inside a digest phase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angularjs-digest

I have code like this:

```
someRequestToServer().then(response => {
  console.log('phase before nav = ' + $rootScope.$$phase);
  $location.path('/somepath');
  console.log('phase post nav = ' + $rootScope.$$phase);
  return response;
});
```

both of the print lines return with '$digest' which implies I am in a digest cycle ... yet the $location.path call is simply not working -- specifically browser URL browser doesn't change. In fact this is the only part that does work.

Also, after the call, location.path() returns the proper URL, what is failing is its ability to propagate to the browser and automatically route the page. While I am able to force the routing with a $route.reload() (as suggested in comments), I still can't get the browser URL to change which puts the page in bad place where the URL and the state of the page don't match.

I was sort of able to work around this by using window.location.href directly, but for various reasons this is not a great solution.

there is a lot about $location.path not working because it is called outside of an angular scope (therefore you have to force it with an apply), but any ideas when it seems like it is in digest cycle?

Comment: need more information, can you post your routing config?

Comment: Have you tried calling $route.reload() after the location function? see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Comment: so $route.reload() reloads the page ... but the URL in the browser isn't changed. which puts the page in an odd state.